# Can i remove the "ATX12V" 4 pin cable from server desktop computer

Tags: power-supply

I have the Dell server and it was running fine.
But it was not powering up and i chnaged the power supply it did the same thing.

i turns on for few seconds and then it turn offs.

I then removed the 4pin "ATX12V" from motherboard and it started ok.

can i keep it removed

Comment: To be clear, you *are* talking about pins 11-12/23-24 of the splittable 20/24 pin motherboard connector right, not the standalone 4-pin standby power connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that provides additional power to the CPU. As soon as the CPU is under enough load to require additional power you will most likely either blue screen or shut down.

Comment: My desktop is still under warranty , so should i call dell

Comment: @Moorage - I would.

Comment: I have attached the Hard drives on other pc so that server OS keep ru ning , will the dell people rquired those hard drives or they can fix the PC without those drivez

Comment: @Moorage - I don't work for Dell, so I can't answer that question. I quick call to their support should clear up any questions that you have.